# Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, tornado

Executed this for the first time and getting exception at app.listen(port)

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, World this is a python command executed from the  backend.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", basicRequestHandler)
    ])

    port = 8882
    app.listen(port)#Getting exception here 
    print(f"Application is ready and listening on port {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Please add more context to your question and format the code in the monospace environment. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidelines on the amount of information to be provided while asking questions.

Comment: It would be useful to know what exception you're getting there, but I assume it's `[Errno 98] Address already in use` which means you have another process listening on that port (could even be the same app started earlier).

Comment: **[NotImplementedError]** this was the error showing.

Comment: I just ran your code above and it works OK on my system (Archlinux, Python 3.8). What OS, Python version do you have?

Comment: I am using Windows  OS and Python 3.8.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: File "C:\Users\habel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python 3.8:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import asyncio

class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, World this is a python command executed from the  backend.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", basicRequestHandler)
    ])
    port = 8882
    app.listen(port)
    print(f"Application is ready and listening on port {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

@gdi313's answer is correct, but let me explain why we have to include asyncio into our code,

till python3.7 Tornado selects 'WindowsSelectorEventLoop' as default, whereas python 3.8 default is not compatible with windows

Thats is why if your application runs on windows using tornado have to have line 
"asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())" at the beginning

Hope this is useful to someone who is facing the error!

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/2686/files